Full size plotly plot when exporting jupyter notebook to slides with nbconvert
I'm exporting my jupyter notebook that containing a plotly plot as slides using nbconvert. The plot should fill the entire slide in the exported document.
Here's a minimal example of my code:
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=[0,1],y=[0,1])
fig.show()

And I'm exporting it in VScode with the command:
jupyter nbconvert minimal_notebook.ipynb --to slides --post serve --no-input --no-prompt

I tried to specify the absolute size with fig.update_layout(width=1920,height=1080) or allowing autosize fig.update_layout(autosize=True) and that changes the size somehow, but the container in which the plot is displayed stays the same, the plot is then gets a scrollbar. I also searched if I can somehow change the reveal template to my needs, but I didn't find out how.
